# Prof. Murty's B. Sc. Thesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Can any of you guys help me to find out if there is a retrodigitized copy of M. Ram Murty's 1976 thesis available on the online database of Carleton University Library?

I really hope this question is appropriate for MO. Thanks in advance for your replies.

**Sources**

1. [Carleton University Library](https://login.proxy.library.carleton.ca/login?qurl=http%253a%252f%252fproquest.umi.com%252flogin%253fCOPT%253dREJTPTNiMGYmSU5UPTAmVkVSPTI%253d%2526clientId%253d13709)
2. **M. Ram Murty**. *On the existence of euclidean proofs of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions*. B. Sc. Thesis, 1976, Carleton University Library.

**UPDATE** (approx. one year later)**.** I contacted the person in charge of the theses at the university library, she said there wasn't a copy of the said work in the central library and contacted the Math Dept. to see if they had a copy of it, but they answered in the negative. Is there a rationale for this situation?

**ANOTHER UPDATE** ([Molley Malone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molly_Malone) Day 2017)**.** Fellow MO-ers: take a look at what I have just come across while taking a look at the table of contents of the latest issue of the *Nieuw Archief voor Wiskunde*:

http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/euclidean.pdf

I can't believe my eyes!

Comment: Did you try contacting Prof. Murty via email (murty at mast dot queensu dot ca)? He might have it...

Comment: I did, but he did not reply. I suppose that either he does not use the email address that appears on his website anymore or that the dullness of my message got him on his nerve.

Comment: If you know a library that has it, then you can probably request it via interlibrary loan.

Comment: Or rather, via an international interlibrary loan... :)

Comment: ...which can get tricky. When I did my PhD I had to request a dissertation from Australia. The library told me to expect delays because (a) they are not sure if that university exists (b) they then need to check if we have an ILL agreement and (c) they can then contact to ask whether a copy still exists in that library down-under. I was rather impressed when, rather than scanning it and sending it to me electronically, I got the original copy which was air-mailed from Australia two weeks later.

Comment: I would do two things.  First, I would call the library and see if they are even remotely willing to loan it.  Second, I would change the title of this to mention Carleton University, so it might attract more useful attention.

Comment: I wanted the MSc of a student at UC Berkeley once. In the end I just gave up, and then I got invited to speak at Berkeley so I showed up, went to the library, and got it myself :-/ 

Comment: Princeton, on the other hand, kept them in the basement, behind a closed door, in a locked cage, the key to which possessed by only the select few Librarians. Just to keep out riff-raff like Kevin :) 

Comment: The link to `login.proxy.library.carleton.ca` is broken.

Answer (score 10):

If you are interested in the contents: the main part of Ram Murty's B.Sc. Thesis might be in his paper

Primes in certain arithmetic progressions, Journal of the Madras University, (1988) 161-169,  which is available online at

http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/euclid.dvi

Also, another paper may perhaps be of interest (more abstract, an extension).

Primes in Certain Arithmetic Progressions,
Ram Murty and Nithum Thain.
Funct. Approx. Comment. Math. Volume 35, Number 1 (2006), 249-259.

Comment: Keith Conrad has an expository paper on this on his web page.

Comment: I have removed some rude comments under what seems a good-faith effort to answer the question.